# Why AudioPlayer crashes App built on Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I am making app that plays music. I am using audioplayer control. But The app keeps crashing whenever I play the music. My code is as below:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Audio Test',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    layout: 'vertical'
});

var startStopButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Start/Stop Streaming',
    top:10,
    width:200,
    height:40
});

var pauseResumeButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Pause/Resume Streaming',
    top:10,
    width:200,
    height:40,
    enabled:false
});

win.add(startStopButton);
win.add(pauseResumeButton);

// allowBackground: true on Android allows the 
// player to keep playing when the app is in the 
// background.
var audioPlayer = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({});
audioPlayer.url = 'cricket.wav';

startStopButton.addEventListener('click',function() {
    // When paused, playing returns false.
    // If both are false, playback is stopped.
    if (audioPlayer.playing || audioPlayer.paused)
    {
        audioPlayer.stop();
        pauseResumeButton.enabled = false;
        if (Ti.Platform.name === 'android')
        { 
            audioPlayer.release();
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        audioPlayer.start();
        pauseResumeButton.enabled = true;
    }
});

pauseResumeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (audioPlayer.paused) {

        audioPlayer.start();
    }
    else {
        audioPlayer.pause();
    }
});

audioPlayer.addEventListener('progress',function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Time Played: ' + Math.round(e.progress) + ' milliseconds');
});

audioPlayer.addEventListener('change',function(e)
{
    Ti.API.info('State: ' + e.description + ' (' + e.state + ')');
});

win.addEventListener('close',function() {
    audioPlayer.stop();
    if (Ti.Platform.osname === 'android')
    { 
        audioPlayer.release();
    }
});

win.open();
```

My Environment:

1. OS X 10.9.1
2. Titanium Sudio: 3.2
3. Titanium SDK: 3.2 GA
4. iPhone5 and iPad Retina (64 bit) iOS 7.0

Comment: Please provide more information, like a crash log, stack trace and what you have tried to solve the issue.

Comment: I have no idea about other possible solutions. Titanium Studio do not offer more log

Comment: The report form OS X log is 2/19/14 9:02:18.809 PM xxxxx[28365]: xxxxx(28365,0x4bdf1a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=3964162048) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: However, Sound still plays a good.